# Server writes data and outputs ajax that fetches that data, but changes in data not always reflected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

A while ago I was working on a project where the main php-page when executed writes some data to a file and then outputs page content including script. This script then right away ajax-loads the data just written to the file through another PHP-page and displays that.
The problem is that sometimes the data fetched by the ajax-function is the data written on the last call of the main-page, and I couldn't figure out why. I solved it in an ugly way by making the script wait a second before doing the ajax-request.

Now I'm on another project with the same problem and it's really bugging me. I've ruled out caching issues by appending a timestamp to the url of the php page that echoes the data.
I've also passed the ajax function to:

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Like expected it didn't solve it.

As I mentioned this does not happen all the time. It doesn't even happen half the time. But it does happen a lot when the system is under a lot of work.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried it with `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: Is each row still being written to the file at the exact moment the call is initiated?. If you are writing to the same file, your file lock might not have been released at the time the next call comes and therefore creating a queue that leads to your problem.

Comment: @take I thought of trying that but.. It's essentially the same as $(document).ready() except this one waits for images and stuff to fully load, am I right? If I did change to that it would probably run later which could make the problem not occur, but not really solve it. I might as well put a time-delay except that would be more reliable. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @user1054844 Do you mean if there are multiple simultaneous calls to the mainpage which all make writes to that file, resulting in a queue? If so, then no, that's not the problem. As for now the page only runs locally on my pc and I only load the page once at a time.

Comment: It does not need to be simultaneous. If you are using automation to generate stress or if the the script has bottlenecks it might cause  queues to form. Basically the back end has not been completed at the time you have reloaded the page, so it will generate queue for the incomplete calls.That would explain why you needed the 1 sec. wait to get current data

Comment: Only way to get rid of that (if the case) is to optimize script and scale the production server to have  enough performance to run the scripts. Other dirty tricks are to post the script to the other page immediately and let the back end write to the file at its own pace

Comment: How are you fetching the newest data written to the file?